# how to properly cite authors in R Markdown with more than 1 name as last name

Tags: yaml, r-markdown, bibtex, bibliography

I am using R Markdown as per the below:

```
---
title: title
author:
- Name1:
    email: email
    institute: med
    correspondence: yes
- name: name2
  institute: med
date: date
bibliography: ref_file.bib
bib-humanities: true
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
        in_header: header.tex 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
    pandoc_args:
    - --lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua
    - --lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua
  word_document:
    toc: no
    pandoc_args:
    - --lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua
    - --lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua
  html_document:
    toc: no
    df_print: paged
header-includes: \usepackage{amsmath}
institute:
- med: etc etc
---

@RN36382 defined...
```

My ref_file.bib shows:

```
@article{RN36382,
   author = {van der Laan, M. J.},
   title = {Statistical Inference for Variable Importance},
   journal = {The International Journal of Biostatistics},
   volume = {2},
   number = {1},
   year = {2006},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

My pdf output is:

"Laan (2006) defined ..." , however, I was expecting "van der Laan (2006) defined..."

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add double brackets ;)

```
...
author = {{van der Laan, M. J.}}
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @manro! :)

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Good luck ;)